# Is there a way to find multiple sibling elements in javascript? without jQuery

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I was asked to refactor the code for a carousel component developed in my company. it calls for group sliding and it's done with `element.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling` or depending on the layout `element.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling`. I would like to re-write it in a shorter more readable way. Is there a way to get multiple siblings of that element in pure Js? Thanks

Comment: Write it first , when you have a problem comeback again

Comment: Isn't it simply a matter of getting the children of the parent element?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that explains the process:

[How to get all of an element's siblings with vanilla JS](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-get-all-of-an-elements-siblings-with-vanilla-js/)

You get the parent node and loop through its children, ignoring any children which are not elements (i.e. which have a `nodeType` other than `1`).